# How can I pass a variable to alert() with $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I want to let the user confirm to deletion of a record by letting them click on the button and the button sends the value Yes to a $_POST request so I can delete the record with PHP, instead it's showing me the javascript file that contains the function.

What am I doing wrong, I've been tinkering and searching for 3 hours straight, while in the back of my mind I know it's a easy fix.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

If you think there is a smarter way to be doing this, please let me know.

```
$(function () {

    $("#DeleteConfirm").dialog({

        buttons: {
                 "Confirm": function() {
                    var DeleteConfirmation = "Yes";                 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data: DeleteConfirmation,
                        success: function(DeleteConfirmation){
                            alert(DeleteConfirmation);
                        },
                        dataType: "text"
                    });

                 },
                 "Cancel": function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }
    });

});
```

Comment: You are going to need to pass an `id` / `hash` or some other kind of unique identifier in your `POST` or you are not going to know what your need to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
if( confirm('Are you sure?')){
    /*proceed?*/
}
```

That is standard javascript. It wraps your AJAX call within the braces and if the user clicks 'yes' - the ajax call will execute. If he click 'no', then nothing happens. The `confirm()` prompt pops up an alert on screen with buttons. The resulted is captured by the `if`. You can also capture the result of that: `var res=confirm('are you sure?');`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `YES` value to a property name:

```
data: { "confirmed": DeleteConfirmation},
```

Then in your PHP you can ready this using `$_POST["confirmed"]`.

This does seem a little redundant however, as the user has already clicked the button to confirm the deletion, so there seems little value in sending the value in the POST request. Sending the `id` of the item to delete would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax is misformed, try:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php",
                    data: {answer: DeleteConfirmation }, //what you send to the php
                    success: function(data){ //answer from your php
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    dataType: "text"
                });

             },
```